# Why did Nas skip out "Bonjour" from his Nasir Film?

Tags: music-video, hip-hop

On Nas' latest album [*Nasir*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasir_(album)), I was wondering if the song *Bonjour* not featuring in the short film (also called [*Nasir*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tiv6sZBXJ_w)) had to do with the rumoured copyright issue that delayed the release time or was just a production decision.

Answer (score 1):

It is most probably because the song doesn't fit with the film.

The film is [described as](https://www.spin.com/2018/11/nas-nasir-short-film-watch/):

> The images are mostly overtly dramatizations of the sociopolitical lyrics and themes in the songs, intercut with images of Nas rapping (often in church).

"Bonjour" is more of a boy and girl song which doesn't fit with the images in the film. The chorus (?) is:

> Oui-oui amour
>   Plenty of kisses, plenty of bisous
>   Good day and best wishes
>   Comment allez-vous?
>   Bonjour

There's not a lot of social commentary in those lyrics.